# Patch CentOS 8 with Microsoft exFAT source Code, Linux Kernel 5.x,

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, patch, exfat

I'm interested on extract original code of Microsoft `exFAT` File System, and Compile it into my `CentOS 8` (I know its the Kernel is very delayed to 5.4 or 5.7 version).

I know the existence of

- https://github.com/relan/exfat
- https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux

I'm interested on

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/exfat

Would be impossible, but I'm interested in test, and don't want to upgrade my Old Kernel (`4.18.0-193`) of `CentOS 8.2-2004` just *patch it*.

**Is it impossible? then Why?**

**What consideration I must have?**

**And What I need to do?**

**NOTE:** The term patch is only add new feature (like a program).

Comment: Why not just compile the version in the second Github link? There are instructions here: https://www.unixtutorial.org/project-compile-exfat-fuse-in-rhel-8/ and it won't do anything with the kernel.

Comment: @NasirRiley according to your link, it is using `root@redhat:/dist # git clone https://github.com/relan/exfat.git` The mine idea is testing porpouse.

Comment: So then compile it and test it. If it doesn't do what you want, then `make uninstall` and delete it. No matter which method you use in your question, you're going to have to compile in order to do anything. There isn't a prebuilt version of it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/8/x86_64/repoview/fuse-exfat.html

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install fuse-exfat
```

You don't need to patch anything. Porting the mainline exfat code to your kernel will be a major undertaking I'm pretty sure you're not ready for.

Comment: Thank you for the confidence vote (lol), you are right! May be I'm not ready, but long time  (2004) I was changing C code for Suse Linux, fixing problem with Programs.
Now, I'm interested in try, like you maybe I'not get the waited result.

Comment: @joseluisbz If you're ready and capable, maybe you should send your CV to RedHat. They are interested in backporting mainline kernel features to their own kernels.

Comment: Thank you. I was reviewing the code of https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux vs https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/exfat and some files are similar.


And the API of 4.18.x kernel has not c functions required in order to translate the fs/exfat from 5.7.x kernel. Maybe I will do work done (Samsung version).